# How can I save a device Token using Cloud Functions (Javascript)

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've managed to push notifications successfully whenever the real-time database changes through FCM, and ultimately through the Firebase Cloud Functions

But I do so by setting a constant with the device token hard-coded in:

```
const registrationToken = "yuYF4yF3nkj....."
```

and then adding it when I fire the notification

```
return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationToken, payload, options);
```

I've also tried to use `context.instanceIdToken;`within:

```
exports.pushNotification = functions.database .ref("....") .onWrite((change, context) => {
const TokenID = context.instanceIdToken;
console.log(TokenID);
```

But it prints out: "undefined"

How can I read my device's token instead of hard-coding it in, since if I were to share this application I would assume the token for each device would be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this you need to subscribe the devices to a topic so that FCM will know to which devices it needs to send notifications. I recommend you to read this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/topic-messaging) for more details on how to do it, but summing it up you need to:

- Subscribe the devices you wish to a topic using the following code:

  ```
  Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "YOUR_TOPIC_NAME")
  ```
- Trigger messages to be sent to everyone subscribed to your topic in your cloud function, you can use this code as an example:

  ```
  var topic = 'YOUR_TOPIC_NAME';

  var message = {
      data: {
          text: 'hello world'
      },
      topic: topic
  };

  admin.messaging().send(message).then((response) => {
      console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error sending message:', error);
  });
  ```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you so much. In-fact, it's even better to have types of users segmented this way. @WytrzymałyWiktor